# Operations not yet implemented in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to spark and I would like to know if there were some redundant task for a developer working on spark that usually need to add code.
Here an example of what I want to say.
I have a RDD containing numbers.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I would like to know if the number 4 is present in this RDD.
If the RDD was a scala list, I would simply do:

```
myList.contains(5)
```

But since it's a RDD I have to do:

```
rdd1.filter(x => x==5).count
```

And check if the result is equal or not equal to 0. Which give me the following function:

```
def contains(rdd1:RDD, number:Int):Boolean {
    rdd1.filter(x => w == 5).count != 0
}
```

(I know I could do that with a dataframe more properly but it was just to explain my question)

Is there others cases for RDD or dataframe where the developers need to do more operations to achieve what they want? (like I did in the example)

Thanks.

Comment: `rdd.filter(_==5).isEmpty` is more `contains` ;)

Comment: @philantrovert Any idea regarding my main question ?